# Problem while executing "python manage.py runserver" in django

Tags: django

I have been using django (2.1.5)  with mysql-connector(2.1.6). Suddenly it has stopped working and giving below error when i do "python manage.py runserver". I have been trying to understand the solution through other question on same issue but it doesn't seem to help.Can somebody please help.

```
(ApiEnv) E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\adventureworks>python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x000000F2445DE9D8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225,
 in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runser
ver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248,
 in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", l
ine 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225,
 in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup

    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in
 populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in i
mport_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2
, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", lin
e 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, i
n __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 305, i
n add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203
, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length(
))
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __
getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 203, in __ge
titem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 336,
 in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line
 101, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: `python manage.py check` will show you  the error

Comment: it gives the same stack trace

Comment: It will not run server unless everything is clear. You have a problem here `self.client = self.client_class(self)` . Where you are using it?

Comment: Add more explanation about **base.py**

Comment: base.py inside django folder is inbuilt file which comes in site-packages when i install django in my virtual environment. I have not made any changes in the same. Path - "E:\Aabha\ApiEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py"